# Refresh Parent Window from child window in IE8

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I create a link with window.open, in new opened window i add a button for close window. I want when my window is close then parent window will refresh, so i use this script :

window.opener.location.href="https://qa.bloom.com/products/customer/account/profile/";
window.close();

In my application parent window use secure server like as https://examples.com but child window not use secure server.

This is working in ff and but in IE 8 it's not working.
Why is IE8 opening a new window instead of just refreshing the existing one?

Please give your suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try following code:

```
window.opener.location = self;
window.opener.location.reload();
window.close();
```

It works great in my IE v8.0

Comment: window.opener.location = self;
It open new window if IE8 with child window URL and window.opener.location.reload();
not working in IE8

Comment: @Seema: not working in IE8 - what do you mean ? does it not work under you IE8 ? - yes, I can agree on that, but in general it works under IE8. The reason might be your IE special security settings or using secure server connection. Sorry, but I can't reproduce your issue and again it works great with my IE8. If you able - try to publish your not working sample.